# Printing unique elements repeated more than once

Tags: java

How do you print a unique array consisting of elements only repeated more than once in an original array in Java? For example, there is an array `a = {1,2,2,2,3,4,5,5}`, the output should be `{2,5}`. It should be using only arrays.

I have attempted the question and this is what I've done so far:

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
        if (a[i] == a[j]) break;
    }
    if (i == j) System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
}
```

The output is all the unique elements in the array, but I am trying to print the ones that are specifically repeated more than once.

Comment: Do you think it would be helpful for you to try to do your own homework yourself first? And then post your code in which you were having difficulties for some concentrated help?

Comment: for loops are your friend...

Comment: What have you done sofar?? we are not here to do your homeworks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question shows zero effort

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Comment: @JonB That's specifically [not a valid close reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260828/5743988).

Comment: @4castle thank you for bringing that to my attention.

Comment: @JonB i have attempted the question and this is what ive done so far: for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++)
  { int j;
   for(j=0;j<i;j++)
   { f
    if(a[i]==a[j])
     break;  
   }
    if(i==j)
     System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
  } //the output is all the unique elements in the array but i am trying to print the one that are specifically repeated more than once.

Comment: @GurzSingh Please [edit] your question if you would like to include your attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input array contains elements that are `Comparable` or otherwise primitive types, you can follow these steps. The goal is essentially to find the last element of all chains of `length > 1`.

1. **Sort** the array using [`Arrays.sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])) (if necessary).
2. **Iterate** over the array, starting at the second element. For each element:

   1. **If** the preceding element is equal to the current element,
      **and** the succeeding element is **not** equal to the current element (or if there is no succeeding element)...
   2. **Then** print the current element.

Note: If you had access to a `HashMap`, there would be an O(n) version of this O(n log(n)) algorithm.

Here it is in code:

```
public static void printDuplicates(int[] a) {
    Arrays.sort(a);
    for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
        boolean precIsEqual = (a[i-1] == a[i]);
        boolean succIsEqual = (i+1 != a.length) && (a[i+1] == a[i]);
        if (precIsEqual && !succIsEqual) {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

[Ideone Demo](https://ideone.com/QtXsTg)

Output: `2 5`